# Adding ArcGIS Online Feature Layer to Leaflet project

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-online, feature-layer, esri-leaflet

I have a hard time adding a simple feature layer from my ArcGIS Online account to a Leaflet project. This is my approach:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet/dist/esri-leaflet.js"></script>

  var esri = L.esri.featureLayer({
           url: "https://services3.arcgis.com/G1WwgjpwOa4JbyeG/arcgis/rest/services/Datensatz/FeatureServer",
           style: function () {
             return { color: "#70ca49", weight: 2 };
           }
         }).addTo(map);
```

So nothing too complicated here, but it just wont't load the layer. When I inspect the Code in my browser it says:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
> ()".

I uploaded the leaflet project on a webserver if you want to check it: [www.wasserwiki.eu/Wasserwiki_App_Mobile](http://www.wasserwiki.eu/Wasserwiki_App_Mobile)

Comment: Try adding the /0 at the end of the service url, "https://services3.arcgis.com/G1WwgjpwOa4JbyeG/arcgis/rest/services/Datensatz/FeatureServer/0" Works for me.

Comment: Wonderful, this is the solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `/0` to the end of the URL, like:

```
var esri = L.esri.featureLayer({
 url: "https://services3.arcgis.com/G1WwgjpwOa4JbyeG/arcgis/rest/services/Datensatz/FeatureServer/0",
 style: function () {
   return { color: "#70ca49", weight: 2 };
 }
}).addTo(map);
```